# CrystalDiskinfo "Caution" on WDC Black HDD

Tags: hard-drive, bad-sectors

Crystal Disk Info on one of my WDC Black shows Caution like on screen:

[image: Screenshot from CrystalDiskInfo showing "Health status: Caution", with warning for "Current Pending Sector Count: 3" and "Uncorrectable Sector Count: 2"]

The disk is empty, data from it was transferred elsewhere. So data loss is not a problem.

tl;dr - can I still use this disk for non-important data storage/usage on a mostly gaming PC?

Longer version:
I managed to fix one of my PC (*actually managed to find time to check it, not really repair anything) and it seems that one of the drives that was used in it has problems - CrystalDiskInfo shows there are warning statuses on "Current Pending Sector Count" and "Uncorrectable Sector Count" and also the "Read Error Rate" has a rather big Raw Value (compared to other HDDs from that PC that have 0 in Rear Error Rate and similar Power On Count/Hours as all were bought and used from the same day): (link above)

Can I still use this disk in my setup - 2 SSD (one for OS and one for games/programs) and 1 HDD for non-important data (stuff that I either can easily recover or I already have a backup of)? Or it's not really worth and I will most likely get BSODs and/or Read/Write errors on the HDD and will just mostly frustrate myself with it and since I have other WDC Blacks in better shape it's better to use one of them instead?

I did Windows Scandisk (with both options separately, the "scan for and attempt recovery of bad sectors" took like 11 hours to finish) and the result was that Windows did find bad sectors and repaired them, but CrystalDiskInfo still shows "Caution".

I tried to do HDTune Full Scan (or maybe it was Active Disk Monitor, one of those) but aborted the process after like 3 hours when the progress was at like <10% but the scan showed like 1-3 bad sectors on the drive.

I read that I can try to fix logical bad sectors with software like MHDD but in this situation is it really worth the time?

And as for "why do you even want to use this HDD in the first place" - the PC I want to use "had it's issues" so I consider it as a risky one, that's why I plan to use it until it still runs (it has decent specs for it's purpose) and if I can avoid accidental failures on good hardware I would like to skip  using good hardware and use other that I have (the SSD already have some usage on them, those also aren't new ones).

Thanks :)

Comment: The disk belueves it is failing. Its not a good idea to tryst data to it, and its likely cheaper (in time) to replace the disk then reacquire the data when it goes.  That said there is nothing stopping you using it if you dont value your time or the data on it.

Comment: Also  the failures are likely to get progressively worse.

Comment: @davidgo That would make a good answer if you could get the typos under control :)

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with the disk. Most manufacturers use 100 or 200 as a *best value*, and those are the normalized values that are displayed. I see no reason for it to be flagged as "Caution". It seems like a new disk with only 82 Power-On Hours. Try another product such as [Speccy](https://www.ccleaner.com/speccy).

Comment: @harrymc You should be looking at the raw values. Current, worst and threshold are normalized and vendor-specific. This drive has been spinning for over 13k hours and has bad sectors.

Comment: @gronostaj: Some raw values have internal structure composed of bit-fields, which is why it's better to use a program that understands them, like CrystalDiskinfo or Speccy.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Seems that after doing a wipe and remap with MHDD the drive works way better - hdtune full scan and active disk monitor full scan complete in like ~1-2hours (not previously <10% after 1hour), they show 0 bad sectors. HDTune benchmark from 6mb-140mb fixed to 90mb-140mb. CrystalDisk only shows C6 Uncorrectable Sector Count (RAW: 2), the C5 Current Pending Sector Count got fixed and is now green with RAW: 0. Either way I will stop using the drive if I will start to get BSOD/RW errors but maybe it will last another 2-3 years.
PS no idea how can I close this thread :(